# Calling stored procedure in mysql with IN OUT parameters which returns result of insertion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in MySQL stored procedure. I want to check whether insert query in procedure is executed or not with return i.e.string true or false on basis of row affect. to OUT parameter.My code like below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_set_roles`(in p_rolename varchar(20),
in p_description varchar(25),out strresult varchar(20))
BEGIN

insert into tbl1(rolename,roledesc) 
values(p_rolename,p_description);

SET @strresult="True";<br>
END
```

I tried but I got `Null` value in the string `@strresult=null`.
Please help it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the problem is that you are not referencing the `strresults` OUT parameter correctly. Rather you are creating a temporary variable of the same name and assigning a value to that.

Try changing to this :

```
SET strresult="True";
```